# Setting PHP session Variable before redirecting to new page using HREF

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, session

I have a table that is pulling a list of IDs from a MySQL table named `auctiontable` and listing the results in rows on the table.

I can easily add `?aid="1"`or  `?aid="2"` at the end of the `href` to use `$_GET`, but I want the user to have NO control over the variable when it's linked on the other page and would need to set it AFTER they click the row that they want to use but BEFORE it goes to another page. (if that makes any sense)

Is there any possible way to set a `PHP` session variable when a user clicks an `href` and THEN link to the next page with that session variable set corresponding to which item they clicked on the table?  Using either PHP or Javascript, or anything?

Comment: Anything in the URL means that the user has control over it. Setting data in the session is very heavy handed and can lead to problems if the person's using more than one tab, data from one window can contaminate another. What's the matter with these parameters?

Comment: The value I'm trying to set in the session is the auction ID.  The main ID that will be used to make sure all the items they enter in the database are associated with that particular auction number.  It's not something I feel that should be in the URL, easily accessible.

Comment: Also, all the items that are pulled from the database will use this auction ID, especially when invoicing, so I feel as if having it in the URL is a possible security issue waiting to happen.

Comment: It is also only being set one time, and it is required.  The only time that they will be able to change the session is by logging out and logging back in, then it will automatically make them select the auction they want to be in again, so If they have multiple tabs, it will still be associated with the same auction.  At least from my understanding

Comment: If manipulating that parameter can cause security problems then your entire model for handling these is flawed. Verify that any arguments you're given make sense. *Never* blindly use data given by the user. It doesn't matter if it's in the URL, or in a form, or somehow stored in the session, you need to validate it before you create database records. Things change, sessions become invalid, permissions change.

Comment: So, what if there is two auctions running simultaneously with IDs 1 and 2.  If I add aid=1 at the top and they are entering items, if for whatever reason that number gets changed to aid=2, and it's still a valid number, how would I be expected to validate that?  It's still valid.  I can easily validate an auction that doesn't exist, but what if the number is a valid number

Comment: If it's a valid number and the user is allowed to perform that action, what objection would you have to completing it? I'm not sure why you'd prevent this. It seems overly paranoid that you'd block a legitimate action just because the link wasn't clicked correctly.

Comment: Don't forget that most [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) have some kind of routing layer that can blend these parameters into the URL itself. `/auctions.php?id=1` becomes `/auctions/1` which is a lot cleaner. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) has very good support for this and gives you many ways to validate the request and user permissions.

Comment: Ok, great.  Those are very valid points and I appreciate your insights.  I'm just a little overly paranoid just because if something gets changed for whatever reason, then it could potentially cause issues when invoicing, and lost profits for the person using the software; so I'm very paranoid because I'd rather not get sued. lol.  I'll definitely look into Laravel, I have not heard of that before.  You learn something new every day! :)

Answer (score 0):

Bind the href with onclick event with some function and when user will click on href, then the function which will be called by onclick event- will call a php file on server by ajax. php file will create the session and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

use `submit` button of `form` instead of `<a></a>` tag like following

```
<form method='post'>
<button type='submit' name='click' value='<?php echo $aid; ?>'>Click</button>
</form>
```

Now you can set session and redirect to whatever page you want after that submit button with `id` value is clicked like following

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['click'])&&!empty($_POST['click']))
{
$id=$_POST['click'];
$_SESSION['id']=$id;
header("location:yourpage.php");
}
?>
```

i hope this works.if error comes feel free to comment,i'll do my best.